# JQuery blur function ( from tutorial)

Tags: jquery

I am following this tutorial, the instructor is going quite fast and not explaining some parts so I am googling lots of documentation and so far its going pretty good. One thing I cant really understand why is that for my .on('blur',function(){.., I need to include function(){} after the duration of 400ms. Why did I not have to include function(){} when I used the focus function? If so, what the heck is the purpose of that function anyway? The instructor just typed this in and i'm not really sure why. By the way I am making a small search engine and the instructor is going through how to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var searchField = $('#query');
    var icon = $('#search-btn');

    $(searchField).on('focus',function(){

        $(this).animate({

            width:'100%'

        },400);

        $(icon).animate({
            right:'100px'
        }, 400);
    });

    $(searchField).on('blur', function(){
        if(searchField.val() == '')
        {
            $(searchField).animate(
                {
                width:'45%'
                },400,function(){});

            $icon.animate({
                right:'45%'
                },400,function(){});


        }

});

})
```

Comment: Have you watched the tutorial all the way through? Are you sure the instructor isn't going to fill out those functions later?

Comment: oh no I havent. Good call.. I guess those will just be filled with other stuff later?

Comment: That function argument is optional, but if you provide it, you can execute code in it that runs when the animation is complete.

Comment: @trincot, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the empty function block here?:

```
$(searchField).animate(
    {
        width:'45%'
    },400,function(){});  // <-- in here
```

That's a callback function.  Since the animation is an asynchronous operation (which should take 400 ms in this case), it doesn't block the code to wait for it to complete.  So if there's something you want to happen *after* it completes, it would go in that function block.

For example, consider this:

```
$(searchField).animate(
    {
        width:'45%'
    },400,function(){
        console.log('first');
    });
console.log('second');
```

Since the code is asynchronous, `'second'` will actually be logged to the console *before* `'first'`.  This is because while `.animate()` "does its thing" asynchronously, the rest of the code continues to execute.  The callback is then invoked after that asynchronous operation.

Since the function block is empty, you don't actually need it and can probably just omit it entirely.  *However*, it's possible that the instructor in this tutorial is putting it there as a placeholder for a future step.

Comment: Thanks so much.. that makes so much sense.

Comment: I was wondering, we could of course make another function seperately, instead of putting a function after the 400ms. Is the difference simply that the function when put as a parameter ( after the 400ms) , will occur directly after the animation? If we made a completely seperate function doing the same thing it would occur right away? Just trying to see the value of making a callback function

Comment: @Munt: I'm not really sure what you're asking there.  If you put code inside of the callback, it's executed after the asynchronous operation completes.  (Basically the last thing that happens inside the `.animate()` implementation is to invoke whatever function was passed to it.)  If you put that code *after* `.animate()` sequentially, then it will be invoked right away and won't wait for the animation to complete.

Comment: Hi, I made a new question follow up to this, if you have time could you check it out?